# mysql_insert_id(); keeps returning '0'

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to grab the id after a query using `mysql_insert_id();`, but I'm still getting 0 despite the fact that

1. I've placed it after the query itself and
2. I've made sure that the id (called P_Id) has AUTO_INCREMENT.

Code below:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(-connectiondetails-);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO clients (Name, Email, Address, Phone, Date, Service, ExtraOne, ExtraTwo, ExtraThree, ExtraFour, ExtraFive) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[service]','$_POST[extra1]','$_POST[extra2]','$_POST[extra3]','$_POST[extra4]','$_POST[extra5]')";
$idit = mysql_insert_id();
echo $idit;



if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

}
else
{
    echo "Error message goes here: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Thinking *"Oh okay maybe I have to actually query it first"*, I did the following but came up with the same result:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(-connectiondetails-);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO clients (Name, Email, Address, Phone, Date, Service, ExtraOne, ExtraTwo, ExtraThree, ExtraFour, ExtraFive) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[service]','$_POST[extra1]','$_POST[extra2]','$_POST[extra3]','$_POST[extra4]','$_POST[extra5]')";



if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    $idit = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $idit;

}
else
{
    echo "Error message goes here: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Any idea where I went wrong? I've gone through other threads but nothing seems to be working for me. Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT**: I have changed mysql_insert_id(); to mysqli_insert_id(); and this time it didn't even return a 0, just blank.

**EDIT 2**: Thank you mbouzahir - your solution worked :)

Comment: mysqli_insert_id instead of mysql_insert_id

Comment: use mysqli_insert_id($con)

Comment: don't use echo to see the value of $idit, use var_dump($idit); that way it won't be "blank" as you described, but NULL

Answer (score 4):

Tried using `mysqli_insert_id($con)` instead of `mysql_insert_id()` in your second example?

Comment: I just did to no avail. This time it didn't even return 0 - it's just blank.

Comment: The OP is not executing the $sql statement so it doesn't matter what statements are placed after it or if they are using msql or mysqli.

Comment: Hey Jeff, the sql is executed in the if statement. I've tested it, and it posts to another page just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements with parameter binding. Try this (and yes, I'm using the OOP API because it's a damn site cleaner)

```
$con = new mysqli(-connectiondetails-);
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    throw new Exception($con->connect_error, $con->connect_errno);
}

$stmt = $con->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO clients (Name, Email, Address, Phone, Date, Service, ExtraOne, ExtraTwo, ExtraThree, ExtraFour, ExtraFive)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

if ($stmt === false) {
    throw new Exception($con->error);
}

// you should probably check here that all required POST params are present

$stmt->bindParam('sssssssssss',
    $_POST['name'],
    $_POST['email'],
    $_POST['address'],
    $_POST['phone'],
    $_POST['date'],
    $_POST['service'],
    $_POST['extra1'],
    $_POST['extra2'],
    $_POST['extra3'],
    $_POST['extra4'],
    $_POST['extra5']);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error);
}

echo $con->insert_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$con=mysqli_connect(-connectiondetails-);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO clients (Name, Email, Address, Phone, Date, Service, ExtraOne, ExtraTwo, ExtraThree, ExtraFour, ExtraFive) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[service]','$_POST[extra1]','$_POST[extra2]','$_POST[extra3]','$_POST[extra4]','$_POST[extra5]')";



if (mysqli_query($sql,$con))
{
    $idit = mysqli_insert_id();
    echo $idit;

}
else
{
    echo "Error message goes here: " . mysql_error($con);
}
```

Comment: OP is using *MySQLi*, not the deprecated MySQL extension